Is a finite locally-free sheaf free on all open affine covering?
If $\mathscr{F}$ is a rank $r$ finite locally-free sheaf over a smooth irreducible curve $X$ and $U_i$ any covering of $X$ by affine open sets, is true that
$$\mathscr{F}|_{U_i} \cong \mathcal{O}|_{U_i}^r $$
for all $i$?

Please show your approach.
